# Find classes that does not override method

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there any way in IntelliJ IDEA to search for classes that does not override a certain method?

Let's say I have these classes:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
  public void methodThatMightBeOverridden() {
  }
}

public class ConcreteClassWithOverriddenMethod extends BaseClass {
  @Override
  public void methodThatMightBeOverridden() {
    super.methodThatMightBeOverridden();
  }
}

public class ConcreteClassWithoutOverriddenMethod extends BaseClass {
}

public class AnotherConcreteClassWithoutOverriddenMethod extends ConcreteClassWithoutOverriddenMethod {
}
```

Is it possible in IntelliJ to find all extensions of `BaseClass` that does not override `methodThatMightBeOverridden()`? Note that I would need to find classes even though they do not directly implement `BaseClass`. In the example above, that would be `ConcreteClassWithoutOverriddenMethod` and `AnotherConcreteClassWithoutOverriddenMethod`.

I know how to use *type hierarchy* to find classes where the method is overridden, but have not found a way to do it the other way around.

I have tried googling for it without any luck. Also, this is a simplified example. In the real code we have many implementations of the sub classes, of which some does not extend the class.

Comment: You could just make the method in the base class abstract and check in which implementations you get a compile error. Not a solution with IntelliJ, but it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the support for this. By standing on the method and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (or *Navigate* -> *Method Hierarchy* in the menu), you get a nice view of all overriding methods:

[image: Method Hierarchy]

Here I put all four classes in a class called `Test` as below, hence the *"in Test"* text after the class names. The picture is pretty self explanatory, but the minus sign means that the class does not override the method.

```
package test;

public class Test {

  public abstract class BaseClass {
    public void methodThatMightBeOverridden() {
    }
  }

  public class ConcreteClassWithOverriddenMethod extends BaseClass {
    @Override
    public void methodThatMightBeOverridden() {
      super.methodThatMightBeOverridden();
    }
  }

  public class ConcreteClassWithoutOverriddenMethod extends BaseClass {
  }

  public class AnotherConcreteClassWithoutOverriddenMethod extends ConcreteClassWithoutOverriddenMethod {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Structural Search. Use a search template like this:

```
class $A$ extends $B$ {

   void $m$();
}
```

Where under `Edit Variables` variable `m` has text/regexp `methodThatMightBeOverridden` and min+max occurrences count of `0`. And variable `B` has text/regexp `BaseClass` and the `Apply constraint within type hierarchy` checkbox enabled.

Comment: Your solution works. However, my example classes were simplified, the real ones are generic. I guess that it would be possible to extend the structural search to allow for generics too.